# Tangled up in sequences and recurrence relations

Tags: difference-equations, sequence

I took a trip through sequences and recurrence relations and I got tangled up since the documentation didn't help much. I'm sure you can.

Given a sequence

```
s = {0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503, 1014, 2037, 4084, 8179, 
   16370, 32753};
```

I'd like to find a recurrence relation for `s` and try

```
fr = FindLinearRecurrence[s]

(* Out[150]= {4, -5, 2, 0} *)
```

Now the question: what does this list of four elements mean? How does the recurrence relation look like? I couldn't find an Explanation in the documentation.

Of course I tried what I would naturally consider the inverse, LinearRecurrence.
But I even did not understand which arguments I had to put into the function.

Ok, I found a recurrence relation, but with another approach, which was a little adventurous.
My question here is: how is this track to be passed correctly?

Here we go

```
fs = FindSequenceFunction[s]

(* Out[160]= DifferenceRoot[
 Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {2 - \[FormalN] - 
     2 \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 
    0, \[FormalY][1] == 0, \[FormalY][2] == 1}]] *)
```

Here we can spot a recurrence relation together with initial conditions (we also replace [FormalX] by X)

```
eq = {2 - \[FormalN] - 
     2 \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 
    0, \[FormalY][1] == 0, \[FormalY][2] == 1} /. {\[FormalY] -> 
    y, \[FormalN] -> n} 

(* Out[163]= {2 - n - 2 y[n] + y[1 + n] == 0, y[1] == 0, y[2] == 1} *)
```

Trying to solve it in the usual way

```
RSolve[eq, y[n], n]
```

> During evaluation of In[164]:= RSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the
>   general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty
>   solution. >>

```
(* Out[164]= {} *)
```

Again a failure! I'm not very lucky this time ...

Ok, let's RSolve the equation with only one initial condition (as it should be for a difference equation of order 1, I don`t understand the two Initial conditions under DifferenceRoot[] above):

```
yy[n_] = y[n] /. 
   RSolve[2 - n - 2 y[n] + y[1 + n] == 0 && y[1] == 1, y[n], n][[1]] // 
  Simplify

(* Out[206]= 1 + 2^(-1 + n) - n *)
```

This seems to be ok.

```
Table[yy[n], {n, 1, 16}]

(* Out[210]= {1, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503, 1014, 2037, 4084, 8179, 16370, 32753} *)
```

Except for the first term it is the case.

I'm sure all this can be done much better and shorter, and I hope you can help.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

```
s = {0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503, 1014, 2037, 4084, 8179, 16370, 
   32753};
```

On my setup, `FindLinearRecurrence` returns unevaluated with this sequence

```
 fr = FindLinearRecurrence[s]
```

> FindLinearRecurrence[{0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503, 1014,
>   2037, 4084, 8179, 16370, 32753}]

```
fs = FindSequenceFunction[s]
```

[image]

```
Clear[a]

yy[1] = 0;
yy[n_Integer?Positive] = a[n] /. RSolve[{a[n] ==
      2 a[n - 1] + n - 3, a[2] == 1}, a[n], n][[1]]
```

> 1/2 (2 + 2^n - 2 n)

Verifying that `FindSequenceFunction` and `RSolve` give equivalent results

```
With[{r = Range[Length[s]]},
 s == fs /@ r == yy /@ r]
```

> True

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon. Hence V10 on Mac is weaker than my V8 on Windows. At least FindLinearRecurrence[s] resulted correctly in {4, -5, 2, 0}. The only weak point was myself then. But now I understand how to interpret this list. Still - as I said before in this discussion - the corresponding recurrence relation differs from the one inside DifferenceRoot[]

Comment: I wrote the equations in `RSolve` from the `DifferenceRoot`. The second initial condition (yy[1]= 0) handles the anomalous first element in the sequence. You get the same result with a direct use of `DifferenceRoot` as `y[n] /. RSolve[{2 - n - 2 y[n] + y[n + 1] == 0, y[2] == 1}, y[n], n][[1]]`.

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: yes Bob, thanks. That's what I did already in my question.

Answer (score 3):

From the details section of [`ref/FindLinearRecurrence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLinearRecurrence.html), it says

> `FindLinearRecurrence` gives the shortest kernel *ker* which reproduces list from `LinearRecurrence[ker,init,\[Ellipsis]]`. The initial list *init* comes from the first elements in list.

The key to using `LinearRecurrence` is that the second argument has to be as long as the first argument (the result from `FindLinearRecurrence`), e.g.

```
LinearRecurrence[{4, -5, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, 15]
(*
{0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503, 1014, 2037, 4084, 8179, 16370}
*)
```

Comment: @ rcollyer: thanks. That explains the usage. Would have expected this in the doc.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze it is in the docs. You just have to dig a little to find it.

Comment: @ rcollyer: I dug ... but no nugget I found. Could you tell me the exact location, please? My feeling is that something like your example should appear very early in the doc of this item.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I list the line I found in the Details section of the docs for `FindLinearRecurrence`. Its the second, first line there (of two). The link to `LinearRecurrence` provides use details, but mostly I just guessed.

Comment: @ rcollyer: thanks for your effort. But I don't have any Details section. Maybe I'm "vinctim" of $Version -> "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze that will do it. In that version, it's called: More Information. Also, the link in my answer is to the most recent docs.

Comment: @ rcollyer: I finally found it. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

First, the correct interpretation of the output {4, -5, 2, 0} is that your sequence satisfies the recurrence $a_n = 4a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}+0a_{n-4}$.

It might be confusing as to why the 0 term is there, but the reason is that your fourth term would not follow the rule correctly (which, in all honesty, really means that your first term is ``wrong"). You have an order-three recurrence that has four initial values, but Mathematica's brain, that doesn't make sense, so it makes it order 4. Try something like:

`FindLinearRecurrence[Join[Table[7,{i,1,10}],Table[Fibonacci[i],{i,1,100}]]`

to see how it might over-complicate this type of recurrence (you ought to get `{1,1,0,0,0,...}`).

Anyway, anomaly aside, you can reproduce your sequence as:

```
LinearRecurrence[{4, -5, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, 10]

(* output: {0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, 58, 121, 248, 503} *)
```

Note that this is not the same as:

```
LinearRecurrence[{4, -5, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, 10]

(* output: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} *)
```

Note that `FindSequenceFunction` doesn't give you a linear recurrence -- it has other stuff in it. I'm not sure which one is better for you, but if you truly want the linear recurrence, you should use `FindLinearRecurrence`.

Comment: @ Kellen Myers: thanks for the hints. I did not intend to find the recurrence relation by applying  FindSequenceFunction. But it accidentially did something like providing just a recurrence relation rather than givin the relatively simple sequence function.

Comment: @ Kellen Myers: let me add that the "wrong" way (via FindSequenceFunction) produced even a first order difference equation. But this was inhomogeneous. BTW: how are inhomogeneous difference equations represented?

Comment: To my knowledge, just as `DifferenceRoot` objects. I don't know if there are other ways of representing them analogous to `LinearRecurrence` but I don't know any.